# I can't see this folder : Branding (SQL Server Report 2016 SP1)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm going to try again.

My version is: SQL Server Report (Standard SP1) and when I go to **Site Settings** I only see this three folders :

**(GENERAL) (SCHEDULES) (SECURITY).**

I want to see Branding's folder because I want to costumise my own server.
[link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4567/sql-server-2016-reporting-services-custom-branding-example/) But I can't do : **Upload Branding Package into SSRS.**

What can I do? Is it a problem of this version? Is there any Zip or file that can fix it?

Version 13.0.4001.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is only available in the Enterprise version of SQL Server 2016, not Standard.